How to formally justify fudge factor in this difference equation solution?
In Exercise $11$ from Section $3.3$ of Differential Equations With Boundary Value Problems by Polking, Boggess, and Arnold, we first develop the difference equation $P[n + 1] = (1 + \frac{I}{m})P[n],\ P[0] = P_0$, where $P[n]$ represents an account balance after $n$ compounding periods, and "$I$ represents the annual interest rate, but the interest is awarded in discrete packets, $m$ times per year.  Then the rate awarded during each compounding period is $\frac{I}{m}$."  Then we solve it to obtain $P[n] = P_0(1 + \frac{I}{m})^n$.
Then Exercise $12$ says that Arkady invests \$$2000$ in an account paying $6$% annual interest.
(a)  If the interest is compounded continuously and no additional deposits or withdrawals are made, how much will be in the account at the end of $10$ years?
(b)  If the interest is awarded in discrete annual packets, then you want to use the discrete formula generated in Exercise $11$.  In this case, $m$ = 1, so $P[10] = 2000(1 + \frac{.06}{1})^{10} = \$3581.70$.  Calculate the balance in the account at the end of the $10$-year period if the interest is compounded $2$ times per year, $12$ times per year, and $365$ timer per year.
(c)  Write a short paragraph explaining the point of this problem.
Part (a) is straightforward; solve $\frac{dQ}{dt} = .06Q,\ Q(0) = 2000, Q(10) = $ the solution, which turns out to be $\$3644.24$.  I think the point of this problem, as per request of (c), is that the difference equation solutions are supposed to monotonically increase with $m$, and converge to the differential equation solution as $m$ approaches $\infty$.  Graphing the solutions with $m$ as a slidable parameter (i.e., in Desmos) suggests we can be even more ambitious and see the entire solution curve converge, not just the numeric value at a single point in time.  The confusing part is that following the recipe in (b) doesn't actually appear to accomplish any of this.  What seems to be needed is a "fudge factor" in the difference equation solutions; $P[n] = 2000(1 + \frac{.06}{m})^n$ doesn't converge to the differential equation solution $Q(t) = 2000e^{.06t}$, but $P[n] = 2000(1 + \frac{.06}{m})^{mn}$ does.
I could apply the substitution $t = \frac{n}{m}$, $Q[t] = P[\frac{n}{m}]$ to turn $P[n] = 2000(1 + \frac{I}{m})^n$ into $Q[t] = 2000(1 + \frac{I}{m})^{mt}$.  This has the right form to converge to $Q(t) = 2000e^{It}$ as $m$ approaches $\infty$, but the move feels unjustified, as I've kind of reverse engineered the substitution just to fudge it into the right form.  The new form isn't really a solution to the difference equation anymore, in the sense that $a(x) * b(x)$ isn't really a solution to multiplying out tedious polynomials.  What is the right way to carefully account for this needed $m$ in the exponent?

The smaller the compounding intervals, the higher is the account balance at the end, if you hold the nominal interest rate $i$ constant. The account balance $(C_n)$ is increasing w.r.t. $m$: $C_n=C_0\cdot \left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^m$

@callculus42 I'm not sure how the quantity $C_n=C_0\cdot \left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^m$ is relevant though.  In your notation, $C_n=C_0\cdot \left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^n$ is the difference equation solution, and $C_n=C_0\cdot \left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^{mn}$ is what appears to converge to the differential equations solution when $m$ is large.

$\left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^m$ converges to $e^{0.05}\approx 1.05127$ So the effective yearly interest rate is larger than $i=0.05$. To repeat: The smaller the compounding intervals, the higher is the account balance at the end. They are never equal. The differential equation is for continuous compounding only. In this case the yearly interest rate is $e^{i}-1\approx 0.05127$.

@callculus42 I agree that the smaller the compounding intervals, the higher is the account balance at the end.  I am not trying to keep account balance (as a function of time) constant as $m$ approaches $\infty$.  Rather, I am trying to increase it to the differential equation solution as $m$ approaches $\infty$.  The issue is that the difference equation solution doesn't actually have $m$ in the exponent, so I can't make use of the fact that $\left( 1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^m$ converges to $e^i$.
